# How to finish an Activity inside a dialog? I called finish(); and SecondActivity.this.finish(); but they didn't work

Tags: java, android

In the first case, finish() works properly, but it doesn't work inside the dialog.
This code is from second Activity, in the first case when I call finish() it finishes and return back to MainActivity but in the second case inside the dialog when I call `finish();` the app crashes.

I can do something like

`startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class));`

inside the dialog, but I don't want to recreate the activity. I want to call finish(); inside the dialog.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String content = etContentDetail.getText().toString();
    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.update:

            dbHelper.noteUpdate(id, content, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
          finish()
          break;

        case R.id.delete:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete Note");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continue ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dbHelper.deleteNote(id);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).create().show();

            break;
    }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what class does _onOptionsItemSelected_ codes belong to? Can you show it?

Comment: @ltp onOptionsItemSelected codes belong DetailActivity.java as I said the problem is in the second case when delete an item then it should go from DetailActivity to MainActivity and get the result to (onActivityResult) to update items inside the RecyclerView.

Comment: Don't directly call the methods you put inside your dialog `onClick`. Move them into a single function inside _DetailActivity.java_ instead and then call that function from the dialog.

Comment: Great! I also posted the answer for others reference. Please mark correct if it fixed the issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't directly call the methods you put inside your alert dialog button's onClick. Move them into a single function inside *DetailActivity.java* instead and then call that function from the alert dialog.

In *DetailActivity.java*

```
public void deleteNote(){
   dbHelper.deleteNote(id);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();    
}
```

In your AlertDialog

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
     ((DetailActivity)requireActivity()).deleteNote()
     dismiss()                             
}
```